# Rebuilding SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Some of my SQL tables have 0 rows and yet have a large about of TotalSpace reserved. These SQL tables  are used to temporary hold data (I am not sure why the vendor did not use temp tables).

The only way I can free up this space is to rebuild the tables. I am thinking of automating this process by running the code below after hours.

- Are there any drawbacks of rebuilding a table?

I notice that it also helps defrag the table.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTableName REBUILD
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html REPAIR TABLE seems more reasonnable. `REPAIR TABLE tableABC;`

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you delete or truncate large objects (e.g. tables/indexes that consume more than 128 extents), the deallocation process is deferred over a period of time and done in the background.  Chances are likely that you won't see the total space reserved drop until a bit after your commit is fired off.

For more info on how this works, check out this KB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177495.aspx

> When you drop or rebuild large indexes, or drop or truncate large tables, the Database Engine defers the actual page deallocations, and their associated locks, until after a transaction commits. ... The physical phase occurs after the transaction commits. The allocation units marked for deallocation are physically dropped in batches. These drops are handled inside short transactions that occur in the background, and do not require lots of locks.

If you're dead set on rebuilding the table, there shouldn't be much overhead as you have already stated there are 0 rows in it.  I don't believe this will "fix" the TotalSpace reserved issue you're asking about, but it shouldn't be of any worry as the engine will reuse those yet-to-be deallocated extents if you need to stuff more data into that table.  Your best bet is to just wait for the space to free up on it's own over time.

> If this space is required for the database to grow before the physical phase is completed, the Database Engine tries to recover space from allocation units marked for deallocation.

Hopefully that helps answer your question.

John

Answer (score 0):

You should really ask the vendor why the product does this, but I suspect in the end the process will not really change. The space these tables use, however temporarily, will need to be accounted for in your growth plan. My guess is they are used to precalculate various application statistics, which means they will also grow in size relative to the rest of the data.